# Fragments or activities for open answer questionnaire app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-edittext, nlp-question-answering

I want to make an app where users have to fill in some open questions. I want each question to have its own page, and navigate with a prev and next button. In the end the user has to see an overview of all the questions with their answers. To realize this, should I use fragments or new activities for each question? And what is the best way to use it?

Answer (score 0):

**Fragments.**

Will be easier to communicate between them and collect data from all fragments.
And of course fragments are not that heavy as activities.

So If You want have separate page for question go for fragments. 
And You will have option to learn how to manage fragment back-stack, transition, maybe nice animations etc.